Prevent Android Chrome to implement name of dl files?
I wrote an app with R shiny to daily implement a calendar on android. More practically, it uploads a file (containing a dataframe which represents the calendar), paste the "today" line to the existing dataframe and save the updated calendar. The trick is to always keep the same file/name to keep track of data of every single day.
However, chrome does implement the name of my calendar when I download the new file (calendar(1).RData, calendar(2).RData...). On linux I can fix this by installing extensions but on android, I read a lot about that options, it seems impossible. But most of the articles I read about are before 2020 and I would like to know whether I miss something ? Is it still impossible in 2024 ?
Thx in advance,
